# __weak IBOutlet vs IBOutlet?

Tags: objective-c

In my implementation file, I write this:

```
@interface MyViewController () {
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_example;
}
```

Should I write it with / without the `__weak` keyword?

How does it affect the memory / resource usage?

p.s. I understand that `IBOutlet` is just a keyword to help Interface Builder to link up codes with components in Interface; it has no actual effects on coding.

p.s. It's not about `@property` in header file. Different.

Comment: with `__weak` means your view (not controller) own the outlet. without `__weak` means your controller (and view) own the outlet. in most the cases, they makes no different because the controller own the view and indirectly own the outlet

Comment: Hey @Wain The "duplicated" question is about `@property`. It's different.

Comment: @Raptor Under ARC it's almost the same. The same answer applies there.

Comment: `@property` exposes variable to other classes, while in implementation, the variable remains private. Same?

Comment: @Raptor Not true. You can make properties "private" (in class continuation). You can also make ivars "public" (in public interface header). No real difference there. More importantly, no difference for memory management.

Comment: @Raptor, there is no difference in this perspective whether the outlet is a property or a private ivar.